# Can I change the height of a content string defined inside :after/before pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using :after pseudo-element to show the separator for the title for a card like below.

```css
.lock-flag {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.lock-flag .lock-icon {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.lock-flag .lock-icon:after {
  content: "-";
}

.lock-flag .lock-separator::after {
  content: "|";
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="lock-flag">
  <span class="lock-icon"></span>
  <span class="lock-separator"></span>
</div>
<span class="title">Title</span>
```

The problem is the separator displays correctly at normal size but when screen resizes, the separator size remains the same though the container size (lock-separator) varies based on the screen size as the font-size for body is getting changed through @media.

Please suggest how to resize the separator size. Is this the right method to have separator placed like this?

EDIT:
As per the comment suggested, changed the element from span to div for block display. Still the problem is same.
As seen below, the expectation is to match the height of the separator to lock icon. The heights of the separator and container varies as per pictures 2 & 3.

[image: With 1em size]
[image: Actual size of the separator]
[image: Actual size of the container]

Comment: Have you tried to use `font-size` attribute with `em` units for your content? (below the `#666` color attribute)

Comment: Yes, I tried, but what happens is that, the separator size varies not in sync with container's size. To match with container size, I need to set to 3em for smaller screen whereas it looks much bigger for larger screen.

Comment: @RameshK Sorry, but I don't understand what's the problem. Can you add a picture with the expected result?

Comment: You mean the height of the pseudo-element itself, rather than its font size? In that case you should also set `display: inline-block` or any of the display values that can have a `height`.

Comment: Hey, you say that the problem is caused by a media query, but you never show the media query in the question!

Comment: Hi @amedina, I have attached the image.

Comment: @MrLister,  I changed the container to div. Still the problem is same. About the media query, it just applies global font size based on the screen size.

Comment: @RameshK Well, in that case, instead of using a separator like that, I would consider using a border, it's the best option for the task.

Comment: don't use a glyph to add a this line .. set a width/height for it and add background to create this line and have better control on it. Using glyph will make it behave differently when the font properties change

Comment: @amedina I will try the suggestion. Thank you all for the quick help.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I will give a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RameshK I meant to change the `display` of the `::after` pseudo element, not the span it's in. `::after` pseudo-elements in divs are still inline by default.

Comment: Your screenshots don't match the code in the question. Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal: use `::pseudo` on the element which size varies. In this demo, I chose to vary the dimensions of the `.media` (would be the lock icon in your case) which affects its `::after` but it can be switched to be `::before` of the text on the right (positioned as `left: negative-value;`).
As absolute positioning is involved, you've to make sure there's enough space between icon and text where the separator will be displayed.

➡️ **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPEZNQ)**

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex; /* or flex */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; /* vertical aligning */
  height: 100%;
  outline: 1px dotted #aaa;
}

.media {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  background-color: #0888;
}

.media::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1.2rem;
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  /* height: 100%; can replace t:0 b:0 */
  border-left: 1px solid #444;
}

.tall {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  margin: 1rem;
}

section:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="media"></span>
    <p class="title">Heading</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="media tall"></span>
    <p class="title">Heading</p>
  </div>
</section>
```